# How will a stolen android phone be localised if it was stolen with an disables wifi and localisation?

Tags: google

I lost my android phone today and the wifi and localisation were off.So,i went to google dashboard;and crypte and erase the phone.But i could not find localization because the wifi and localisation were off as i said.Now,i want to know if there is a chance to localise my lost phone.

Comment: You mean "located/location" instead of "localize/localization"?

Answer (score 1):

No, if location is off you will not locate it, now it's too late to do anything. You can go to police with IMEI you have it on phone box, but they don't bother with stolen phones.
And also I think the phone will not be earsed or crypted until it connect to internet, because there isn't way to trigger if phone doesn't connect to internet, this is logic but I'm not sure abot it.